# Make a section style like picture

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, tufte

I need to design a section looking like this:

[image]

which obey this rule on both even and odd pages. I've done this so far:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{xcolor} % for colour
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for sample text

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

% section format
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\normalfont\Large\itshape\color{orange}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{orange}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\thesection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Sub section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

But it needs some edits.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want the orange strip to go up to the end of the physical sheet, or up to the right margin?

Comment: I want it to cover all page width

Comment: And you really want it orange?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Any color works!

Comment: Will it be two-sided?

Comment: Yes, I want to have different even and odd pages also

Comment: @Bernard is it possible? ?

Comment: @HH: I didn't answer because I went to sleep ;o) I tried, but misunderstood the specifications, and had problems due to the class. Now I see the real specs, and I have an idea I must test. I'll do it as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution, working only for one-line section titles:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\geometry{showframe, twoside}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for colour
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for sample text
\AtBeginDocument{\PassOptionsToPackage{explicit, calcwidth, pagestyles}{titlesec}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength\outermargin
\newlength\innermargin
\setlength{\innermargin}{1in}
\setlength{\outermargin}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\textwidth-\innermargin\relax}
\titleformat{\section}%
 {\normalfont\Large\itshape\color{orange}\setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}}% format applied to label+text
 {\llap{\colorbox{orange}{\makebox[\outermargin][r]{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+\fboxrule][\dimexpr\depth+\fboxrule]%
 {\vphantom{lp}\color{white}\bfseries\thesection\enspace}}}}}% label
 {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
{\rlap{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\framebox[\dimexpr\linewidth + 2\fboxrule\relax][l]{\vphantom{lp}}\colorbox{orange}{\makebox[\outermargin][r]{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+\fboxrule][\dimexpr\depth+\fboxrule]%
 {\vphantom{lp}}}}}\hspace{1cm}}% before the title body
[]

 \begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Sub section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @HH: I've posted a code. Is it OK? Note it is designed for one-line section titles.

Comment: How can I move the section name 1cm to the right?

Comment: @HH: Replace `\enspace` with `\hspace{1cm}`. Is my updated answer OK?